# Front wheel DT Swiss C1800 vs CR1600, is it worth the extra bucks?

Tags: wheels

I have to replace my front wheel (700C, disc brake, QR), and I'd like to take the opportunity to upgrade it. My current OEM wheel has a manufacturer weight of 1310g…

It's for a gravel DIY e-bike, usually with some luggage. I'd like something light (considering my price range), yet quite robust. My current tire is a 700x38mm, but I may replace it with 40~45mm.

So far, I'm considering the DT Swiss [C1800](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/wheels/wheels-road/cross-road/c-1800-spline) (130€) or the [CR1600](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/wheels/wheels-road/cross-road/cr-1600-spline) (190€). The [CR1400](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/wheels/wheels-road/cross-road/cr-1400-dicut) (280€) being a bit too expensive.

The C1800 and CR1600 seem to be very similar, the main difference being the hub (370 vs 350). If it were for the rear wheel, I'd pick the 350 hub without hesitation as it's much better. But for the front wheel, I don't know if there is significant difference.

So, I'd like to determine if the CR1600 is worth the extra 60€ over the C1800.

Comment: Sorry - this is pretty much a shopping question and is likely to be closed as off topic.  An on-topic question would be something like "how much difference does the weight of a wheel make" with no reference to brands or prices.  There are a number of these pre-existing questions with answers too, so have a search of the [wheels] category.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't suspect it may be off-topic, as buying parts is such an important part in bicycling ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between these wheels comes in the freehub. The 350 freehub is a ratchet system, whereas the 370 is a pawl system. At the front there's not going to be much difference and you can save your money.

Comment: Actually, there’s one more minor difference: the rim on the 1800-level wheels is pinned, rather than welded. They are a bit heavier than the 1600-level welded rims. Some pinned rims may be lower quality. I’ve got a set of CR1800s, and I don’t feel like it’s a substantive disadvantage. Judging by manufacturer specification, the spokes are the same. I don’t know if there are internal differences between the 350 and 370 level hub apart from the ratchet (e.g. bearing quality), but I believe both models are made in Taiwan, whereas I remember higher models being made in Switzerland.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Actually, I was even about to buy the CR1400 now (as I'm a weight-weenie). But the dicut spokes are a no-no for me, as I want something serviceable with regular, widespread tools. And I'd much prefer not having to remove the tire for truing the wheel… Guess I'll go for the CR1600 then, just paying the extra bucks over the C1800 to be on the safe side about quality.

Comment: weight weenie with an e-bike? that doesn't make much sense....

Comment: I have to carry the bike up stairs, a lot… ;-)